# Problema ao anexar valor à matriz em Python 2

Tags: python, matriz

O problema está em `matrix.append([(x+1), vectorY[x][1]])`.
Por mais que o valor de `vextor[x][1]` seja diferente de `(x+1)`, quando for adicionado vai receber o mesmo valor de `(x+1)`, ficando uma matriz com dois valores iguais, *ex: ([1 , 1])*
Este é link do código completo: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e6e89ee4b4dcc6e6b247#file-spearman_eng-py

```
def createMatrixDi(self, matrixxy):
    matrixxy.sort()
    vectorY = []
    index = 1
    for values in matrixxy: 
        vectorY.append( [ values[1], index ])       
        index += 1
    x = 0
    matrix= []
    while (x < len(vectorY)):
        matrix.append( [(x+1), vectorY[x][1]] )
        x += 1
    return(matrix, len(vectorY))
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: O erro é que a matriz está sendo gerada errada. Ao invés de criar uma matriz do tipo: *([1,2], [2,4],[3,3])* , está sendo criada uma matriz de valores sempre iguais: *([1,1], [2,2], [3,3])*

Comment: E qual a entrada usada? O valor de `matrixxy`?

Comment: Não importa a entrada, sempre vai gerar este erro. Este erro é inexplicável, já estou achando que é bug do Python. Vou utilizar numpy e se der certo coloco a solução aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Simulei a execução do seu código sequencialmente, por partes. Adaptei um pouco o código e fiz o seguinte:

```
a = [[6, 2], [8, 4], [1, 9]]
a.sort()

print(a)

vectorY = []
index = 1

for values in a: 
    vectorY.append( [ values[1], index ])       
    index += 1

print(vectorY)
```

`a` imprimiu:

```
[[1, 9], [6, 2], [8, 4]]
```

`vectorY` imprimiu:

```
[[9, 1], [2, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Depois temos:

```
x = 0
matrix = []

while (x < len(vectorY)):
    matrix.append( [(x+1), vectorY[x][1]] )
    x += 1

print(matrix, len(vectorY))
```

Que imprimiu:

```
([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], 3)
```

Não há qualquer problema com o seu código. De fato, o comportamento indesejado está nesta linha:

```
matrix.append( [(x+1), vectorY[x][1]] )
```

Mas repare que `vectorY[x][1]`, qualquer que seja o `x`, vai pegar o segundo valor de `[[9, 1], [2, 2], [4, 3]]`, que no loop anterior já era sequencial.

Se eu entendi o que você quer, o resultado esperado é:

```
([[1, 9], [2, 2], [3, 4]], 3)
```

Ou seja:

```
matrix.append( [(x+1), vectorY[x][0]] )
```

Comment: Obrigado Mendez! O 'vectorY[x][1]' realmente é sequencial e por isso o erro.